# SSH asking for passphrase on public key with no passphrase set

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, github

I have been using public key authentication on my servers for a while now, but I am experiencing issues on a new 'client' trying to connect to [github](https://github.com).  I have read many threads to verify that my permissions are set up correctly and have generated a new key for github.  The problem I am facing is that ssh is asking for my passphrase even though I did not set a passphrase.  I have even re-made the key to be 100% sure that I did not enter a passphrase.

**ssh -vvv** gives the following related output:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/me/.ssh/github.pub
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1495
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve mygithubusername c3:71:db:34:98:30:6d:c2:ca:d9:51:a8:c6:1b:fc:f7
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp c3:71:db:34:98:30:6d:c2:ca:d9:51:a8:c6:1b:fc:f7
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/me/.ssh/github.pub':
```

I have searched to figure out why it is telling me **PEM_read_PrivateKey** failed, but I cannot find a solution.

I do not use an agent or anything.  I configure my ~/.ssh/config file similar to the following:

```
Host github
Host github.com
Hostname github.com
User git
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/github.pub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a bit trivial, and I'm a goof for not noticing this earlier, but hopefully your answer will provide help to others in the future.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you use the `IdentityFile` option in your `~/.ssh/config` you point to the private, *not the public*, key.

From `man ssh_config`:

> **IdentityFile**
>               Specifies  a  file  from which the user's DSA, ECDSA or DSA authentication identity is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa for protocol version 2.

So, your `~/.ssh/config` entry should look like:

```
Host github.com
Hostname github.com
User git
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/github
```

Comment: I'm such a doofus.  My only saving grace is that this may help other 'doofuses' in the future.

Comment: It's an easy enough mistake to make...

Comment: Just helped me, so I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Color me a doofus.

Answer (score 8):

We had this problem, and it was a cut-and-paste error.  A single `%` symbol had been added to the end of the key file (so the last line was `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----%` ).  There was no error or debug info or anything else to suggest that the key was the wrong length or badly formatted, but ssh asked for a passphrase.

Comment: Similiar thing happend to me. I copied the key from another terminal and copied too much without noticing it.

Comment: I had 4 dashes after END RSA PRIVATE KEY instead of 5

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was the my SSH client does not support ED25519 keys. The solution is to create an RSA key and use it instead.

This problem occurs with [OpenSSH < 6.5](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.5) (run `ssh -V`) and [PuTTY < 0.68](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ed25519.html).

This can be seen in the following output of `ssh -vvv`:

```
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
```

The [first block describes what the client supports, and the second what the server supports](https://wiki.osnexus.com/index.php?title=Custom_SSH_Security#Verifying_the_SSH_security_settings). As you can see, there's no mention of 'curve25519' in the top half, indicating that the client does not support that.

Answer (score 1):

On my team, when this happens it isn't an issue with anything locally. The user's ssh key and/or access hasn't been configured correctly on the server they're connecting to (in our case a hosting platform). For some reason this triggers a prompt for a non-existent ssh key.